# Node.js Expres.js Heroku Toolbelt >Foreman Start - Error: write EINVAL

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, foreman

This is the error I encountered with package.json when running foreman start with Heroku Toolbelt for Node.js

```
 "dependencies": 
{
    "express": "~4.4.0",
    "jade": "~1.3.1"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issues as Jek.  I was using express 4.4.4.  I downgraded express 3.2.6 and it worked, but I shouldn't be forced to use an older version of express just because foreman doesn't support it.

I tried [node-foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman).  And it worked for me. I followed the instructions that included these steps:

1. npm install -g foreman
2. nf start

I would like to know if anyone has additional suggestions.

Comment: I've had this same issue for months, I gave up a while ago. I have been trying again, building up a simple app from scratch. This WORKS. Very simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this issue by changing express version to 3.2.6 as seen below

```
 "dependencies": 
{
    "express": "~3.2.6",
    "jade": "~1.3.1"
}
```

Then I deleted node_modules and did a npm install. Following this a foreman start works perfectly fine.

However I have no idea why it doesn't work when it runs on express 4 but it works when running on express 3.

Comment: I'm getting the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127434/write-einval-error-on-foreman-for-heroku-on-node-js-and-on-port-5000-immediate) problem with EINVAL.

Comment: Any other solution ? :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This answer worked for me, but not acceptable.  I can run my node application successfully with express 4.4.4 locally without using foreman. I can also run my application with express 4.4.4 on a Heroku Dyno with no problem. If I run "foreman start" multiple time in a row, i get different errors.  Foreman is a pain in the a**. I'm about to give up on Heroku and look for a different solution.

Comment: @BarDev it's the same pain point that we face. I'm about to give up on it too. If you do find a different solution, could you share that with me. I'll be glad to try new stuff.

Comment: Since my post on July 4 I've been using node-foreman and it's been working without issue.